# Aggregating data from multiple lists via list comprehension

Tags: python, list

I'm writing the following code to calculate consolidated grades of student to manage their Transcript, but not getting desired output, could someone help me in this,Thanx!

```
def transcript(coursedetails, studentdetails, grades):
    studentdetails.sort()
    coursedetails.sort()
    grades.sort()
    result=[(student,grade,coursedetail)
            for student in studentdetails 
            for grade in grades for coursedetail in coursedetails 
            if((student[0]==grade[0])and(grade[1]==coursedetail[0]))]
    print(result)
```

Input I'm giving is---

```
transcript([("MA101","Calculus"),("PH101","Mechanics"),("HU101","English")],[("UGM2018001","Rohit Grewal"),("UGP2018132","Neha Talwar")],[("UGM2018001","MA101","AB"),("UGP2018132","PH101","B"),("UGM2018001","PH101","B")])
```

Actual Output---

```
[(('UGM2018001', 'Rohit Grewal'), ('UGM2018001', 'MA101', 'AB'), ('MA101', 'Calculus')), (('UGM2018001', 'Rohit Grewal'), ('UGM2018001', 'PH101', 'B'), ('PH101', 'Mechanics')), (('UGP2018132', 'Neha Talwar'), ('UGP2018132', 'PH101', 'B'), ('PH101', 'Mechanics'))]
```

Desired Output---

```
[('UGM2018001', 'Rohit Grewal', [('MA101', 'Calculus', 'AB'), ('PH101', 'Mechanics', 'B')]), ('UGP2018132', 'Neha Talwar', [('PH101', 'Mechanics', 'B')])]
```

Comment: You just asked that question and we told you it was a duplicate

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["Least Astonishment" and the Mutable Default Argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132941/least-astonishment-and-the-mutable-default-argument)

Comment: I've looked over this question and I don't see resemblance to the question mentioned in the previous comment. There are not even any Default Arguments passed.

Answer (score 0):

You may consider changing your structure from a list of tuples to a dictionary as it will be much easier to manipulate the information.

```
def transcript(coursedetails, studentdetails, grades):
    result = {}
    students = {}
    courses = {}
    for course, descript in coursedetails:
        courses[course] = descript
    for sid, student in studentdetails:
        students[sid] = {'name':student}
    for sid, course, grade in grades:
        details = (course, courses[course], grade)
        if not 'grades' in students[sid]:
            students[sid]['grades'] = []
        students[sid]['grades'].append(details)
    return  students
```

This returns a dictionary of dictionaries for your transcript where the student ids are the keys that return a dictionary holding your student's name and grades.

Test:

```
trans = transcript([("MA101","Calculus"),("PH101","Mechanics"),("HU101","English")],[("UGM2018001","Rohit Grewal"),("UGP2018132","Neha Talwar")],[("UGM2018001","MA101","AB"),("UGP2018132","PH101","B"),("UGM2018001","PH101","B")])
```

Result:

```
{'UGM2018001': {'name': 'Rohit Grewal', 'grades': [('MA101', 'Calculus', 'AB'), ('PH101', 'Mechanics', 'B')]}, 'UGP2018132': {'name': 'Neha Talwar', 'grades': [('PH101', 'Mechanics', 'B')]}}
```

If you still want this information in the Desired Output described above, then the following will create a list of tuples exactly as you needed.

```
list((k,v['name'], v['grades']) for k,v in trans.items())
```

Answer (score 0):

This is possible with [`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict):

```
from collections import defaultdict

inputs = [("MA101","Calculus"),("PH101","Mechanics"),("HU101","English")],\
         [("UGM2018001","Rohit Grewal"),("UGP2018132","Neha Talwar")],\
         [("UGM2018001","MA101","AB"),("UGP2018132","PH101","B"),("UGM2018001","PH101","B")]

def transcript(coursedetails, studentdetails, grades):

    d = defaultdict(list)

    courses, students = dict(coursedetails), dict(studentdetails)

    for grade in grades:
        d[(grade[0], students[grade[0]])].append((grade[1], courses[grade[1]], grade[2]))

    return d

res = transcript(*inputs)
```

**Result**

```
defaultdict(list,
            {('UGM2018001', 'Rohit Grewal'): [('MA101', 'Calculus', 'AB'),
                                              ('PH101', 'Mechanics', 'B')],
             ('UGP2018132', 'Neha Talwar'): [('PH101', 'Mechanics', 'B')]})
```

If you *really* need a list of tuples, this is easy to transform:

```
res2 = [(k[0], k[1], v) for k, v in res.items()]

# [('UGM2018001', 'Rohit Grewal', [('MA101', 'Calculus', 'AB'),
#                                  ('PH101', 'Mechanics', 'B')]),
#  ('UGP2018132', 'Neha Talwar', [('PH101', 'Mechanics', 'B')])]
```